# warning initialization from incompatible pointer type - C array of function pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, initialization, function-pointers

I'm having trouble solving this warning

here are my prototypes

```
int doubeInput (int* inputVal);
int squareInput (int* inputVal);
int cubeInput (int* inputVal);
```

the line that has the error is

```
int (*funPtrArr[])(int)={doubleInput, squareInput, cubeInput};
```

this line is in main

```
while (choice >0 && choice <=3)
    {
        (*funPtrArr[choice])(inputVal); 

    }
```

and here are my functions

```
//function to perform the menu option 1,user input passed in
int doubleInput (int* inputVal)
{
    //calculate double
    int answer = (*inputVal) *= (2);
    printf("%d x 2", inputVal); 

    return (answer);
}


//function to perform the menu option 2,user input passed in
int squareInput (int* inputVal)
{
    //calculate square
    int answer = (*inputVal) *= (*inputVal);
    printf("%d x %d", inputVal, inputVal);

    return (answer);

}


//function to perform the menu option 3,user input passed in
int cubeInput (int* inputVal)
{
    //calculate cube
    int answer = (*inputVal) *= (*inputVal) *= (*inputVal);
    printf("%d ^ 3", inputVal);

    return (answer);
}
```

I keep getting this error, I'm very new to C. My functions are not complete yet because I haven't been able to test them.
please help

Comment: Typo: `int doubeInput (int* inputVal);` must be `doubleInput`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*funPtrArr[])(int)
```

declares an array of pointers to functions with an `int` parameter, but your functions have an `int *` parameter. 
So the line should be

```
int (*funPtrArr[])(int *)={doubleInput, squareInput, cubeInput};
```

Comment: ok that did get rid of those errors but now I'm getting another [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'funPtrArr[choice]' makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Comment: what is the type of `inputVal` in main()? If it's `int` you have to pass `&inputVal`